# AngularJS ng-repeat splicing array not updating DOM correctly

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm running into an issue when using ng-repeat to create buttons from an array that is populated through a drag/drop system.

[Here is a screenshot of the page](http://puu.sh/ednwZ/9a104113fa.png). You're suppose to use the Numbers and Symbols to create an expression in the dropzone (gray area). In the screen shot I have a pre tag that is displaying the contents of the array. There is only one object in that array but the repeat is still displaying two. Is there something I'm not understanding about how ng-repeat handles itself when its array is updated?

```js
$scope.arr = [];
//gets called when a number or symbol is dropped
$scope.dropItem = function(draggable, dropzone){
  if(dropzone) {
    var obj = {
      name: draggable.name,
      fragmentId: draggable.fragmentId,
      controlId: draggable.controlId,
      id: hal.utils.generateGuid()
    };

    $scope.arr.push(obj);
    $scope.$apply();
  }
};
//callback for draggables inside dropzone
$scope.reorderItem = function(draggable, dropzone){
  //reorder
  if(dropzone){

  }
  //remove
  else {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arr.length; i++){
      if($scope.arr[i].id == draggable.value){
        $scope.arr.splice(i, 1);
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    }
  }
};
HTML
```

```html
<td class="equation-drop-zone" hal-dropzone="PerimeterEquation" max="10">
  <pre>{{arr}}</pre>
  <button
          ng-repeat="button in arr track by button.id"
          hal-draggable="{{button.name}}"
          value="{{button.id}}"
          hal-text
          control-id="{{button.controlId}}"
          fragment-id="{{button.fragmentId}}"
          drop-callback="reorderItem"
  ></button>
</td>
```

Comment: My guess would be that there are two items because one of them is generated by the ng-repeat as expected, and the other dom is the one dropped. You need to delete the dropped dom item, and add that object into the `$scope.arr` array and let ng-repeat be the only one to generate the dom

Comment: the dropItem function is the one that generates the objects that get put into the array. the draggable element you put into the dropzone just resets back to its normal position.

Comment: It resets back? It doesn't get dropped into the dropped zone? It's hard to debug without a reproducer then.